# Video issues with old server running Boxee

Tags: graphics-card, dell-poweredge, boxee

I have a old Dell Power Edge 1650 1U rackmount server running Windows XP. Dual 1.3 GHz CPU's and 1 GB of RAM. I would like to run Boxee on it, but the 8MB integrated video card will not support it. The font within Boxee just comes up as blocks of colour.

I have a [PCI Radeon R9000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_9000_Series) dual out video card. However when I plug it in I can not get video signal on any of the VGA outs. Is it possible to upgrade the video card on this old of a server, or is it possible to make it work with the older integrated video?

Comment: Any BIOS option to change the graphics card from 'onboard' to 'auto' or PCI?

Comment: Nope, Video is not mentioned anywhere in the BIOS. BIOS version is A11.

Comment: Also, I am willing to change to a Linux operating system if anyone has advice for going down that path.

Comment: If the BIOS does not allow you to change the primary video card then you may be SOL. Are you using the newest BIOS?

Comment: Yes, A11 is the newest.

Comment: I will assume if after the bounty, there is still no answer, what I want to do simply can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Remote Desktop to access the machine, maybe it will render properly.  Could try Logmein.com too, I think it uses its own display driver.

Comment: have not, but if The computer is connected directly to the TV, how would this work?